# Acts 18:24 Ἀπολλῶς Rev 9:11 Ἀπολλύων

Tags: greek, revelation, acts

> And a certain Jew named **Apollos (Ἀπολλῶς G625)**, born at
> Alexandria, an eloquent man, and mighty in the scriptures, came to
> Ephesus. **(Acts 18:24 - KJV)**

> And they had a king over them, which is the angel of the bottomless
> pit, whose name in the Hebrew tongue is Abaddon, but in the Greek
> tongue hath his name **Apollyon (Ἀπολλύων G623)**. **(Rev 9:11 -
> KJV)**

I wounder if Apollo (Acts 18:24, Ἀπολλῶς), the Greek sun god and its possible connection to the "angel of the bottomless pit" as referenced in Revelation 9:11 Apollyon Ἀπολλύων .

Apollyon means "destruction, or destructor"[strong's G623](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g623/kjv/tr/0-1/), to what extent does Apollo means the same thing [strong's G625](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g625/kjv/tr/0-1/)

Are they the very same deity?
Are the root word same and just different Greek suffix?

- Ἀπολλ**ῶς** - Apoll**os**
- Ἀπολλ**ύων** - Apoll**yon**

Comment: You seem to be asking us whether the two terms are related to the concept of heat, to which the answer is no. [The latter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ἀπολλύων) is simply the participle of [ap'ollymi](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἀπόλλυμι), itself a derivative of [ollymi](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ὄλλυμι), meaning *to destroy*. [The former](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo) had many attributes, to which the sun was only the latest accretion; from context, it is the property of eloquence that's being explicitly referenced, since *Apollo* was the patron deity of the oracle of *Delphi*.

Answer (score 2):

**Apollos**

Both BDAG and Thayer suggest that Ἀπολλώς is a contraction of Ἀπολλώνιος (Apollonios) as the case in Acts 18:24 in the Codex Bezea Cantabrigiensis.  Thus, The name means, "belonging to, or of Apollo" (the most famous Greek god.)

**Apollyon**

The Greek Ἀπολλύων definitely means "destroyer".  BDAG offers this comment:

> Whether the writer of Revelation implied a connection with the deity
> Apollo cannot be determined. Indeed, it is questionable, for Apollo
> was the god of purity and recognized for his civilizing influence.

See BDAG for more references and other associations.

**CONCLUSION**

While the names are similar, any association between Apollos and Apollyon appears highly questionable.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same. Remember Yahshua (Jesus) warned of the **scribes**. They have been added characters, and removing others since the beginning. In fact, they also changed the translation γραμματεῖς.SCRIBES, to TEACHERS OF THE LAW, because no only were they Covering up that Yahshua exposed them tampering with The Word, they also sowed among the word of God as in
**Mat 13:25**:

> 25 But while men slept, his enemy came and sowed tares among the
> wheat, and went his way.

> The is why The Kingdom of Heaven is as a HIDDEN BURIED TREASURE Mat
> 13:44

and we are REQUIRED TO SEEK AND FIND IT!
AND ONLY FEW Find Life

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).